# Jave FileNotFoundException(Access Denied)

Tags: java, io, filenotfoundexception

I have created a AWT frame which accepts text input in textarea and can count the number of words and characters or it could save its content to "trial.txt" file.

This is the whole code for reference:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

class trial extends Frame
{
    static TextArea ta=new TextArea("Welcome");
    static Label l1=new Label("Words:");
    static Label l2=new Label("Characters:");
    static Button b=new Button("Count");
    static Button save=new Button("Save");
    static BufferedOutputStream bos;

    trial()
    {
    //Setting position
    ta.setBounds(300,300,300,300);
    l1.setBounds(50,50,100,100);
    l2.setBounds(50,200,100,100);
    b.setBounds(650,300,50,50);
    save.setBounds(650,400,50,50);

    //Setting up file for saving
    try {
        bos=new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("C:\\trial.txt"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    save.addActionListener(new Save());

    //Adding the components
    this.add(ta);
    this.add(l1);
    this.add(l2);
    this.add(b);
    this.add(save);

    //adding actionlistener to button
    b.addActionListener(new actionlistener());

    //setting up frame
    this.setSize(1000,1000);
    this.setLayout(null);
    this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static class actionlistener implements ActionListener
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            String text=ta.getText();
            String words[]=text.split("\\s");
            l1.setText("Words:"+words.length);
            l2.setText("Characters:"+text.length());
        }
    
    }

    public static class Save implements ActionListener
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            String text=ta.getText();
            byte[] arr=text.getBytes();
            try 
            {
                bos.write(arr);     
            } catch (IOException f)
            {
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        trial ttt=new trial();
    }
}
```

I have copied the right path, it is given above in the code. I have also given permission to java to read and write. But the code shows `java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\trial.txt (Access is denied)` .

Comment: "I have also given permission to java to read and write": no you haven't. The exception says so.

Comment: Windows can have some pretty tight restrictions, best to place the file in your uses documents folder as a starting point

Comment: By default, normal users cannot write files in the root of C:

Answer (score 0):

Oh it was very easy just a silly mistake.
Needed to put file name as parameter and not file path.
It is showing no error now but it is not saving the contents of the file to the txt file.

*Edit:It is working now.Thank you all for your help.

Comment: That's because you never close the `BufferedOutputStream`.